# Running coint_johansen cointegration test gives : LinAlgError: Matrix is not positive definite

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, forecasting, vector-auto-regression

I am pretty new to mulltivariate time series, I am trying to make a VAR model with 108 predictors and 1 target variable. While performing the *Johansen Cointegration Test*, I am getting an error

```
LinAlgError: Matrix is not positive definite
```

My code is :

```
def cointegration_test(df, alpha=0.05): 
    """Perform Johanson's Cointegration Test and Report Summary"""
    out = coint_johansen(df,-1,5)
    d = {'0.90':0, '0.95':1, '0.99':2}
    traces = out.lr1
    cvts = out.cvt[:, d[str(1-alpha)]]
    def adjust(val, length= 6): return str(val).ljust(length)

    # Summary
    print('Name   ::  Test Stat > C(95%)    =>   Signif  \n', '--'*20)
    for col, trace, cvt in zip(df.columns, traces, cvts):
        print(adjust(col), ':: ', adjust(round(trace,2), 9), ">", adjust(cvt, 8), ' =>  ' , trace > cvt)

cointegration_test(g)
```

- Where ***g*** is my Time Series Dataframe of shape **(48 rows × 109 columns)** . rows are the date-time index and columns are the predictors/variables.
- Data in few columns ranging from 0-1(For ex : Consumer Price Index) and others in the range of millions(For ex : Population, GDP).
- There are columns in the dataframe which contain negative terms as well(For eg : Change in Employment)
- Few columns also contain zero in them

But when i pass the dataframe after making all the column *stationary* using

```
g = g.diff().dropna().diff().dropna()
```

and then pass the differenced dataframe to `cointegration_test` its giving error as :

```
LinAlgError: Matrix is not positive definite
```

As far as my understanding goes `Matrix is not positive definite` means that the Eigen values associated with it are non-positive.And Eigen-values are only possible for square matrix, but given the data which I am feeding is a non-square...

How can I solve this problem? Where should I look next? Would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned, it is a requisite for a matrix to be nxn dimensional. So what you basically need is:

1. NxN dimensional matrix.
2. Test if it is positive Definitive.
3. In case point 2 fails, you could transform it to be Positive Definitive, a useful link is https://github.com/Cysu/open-reid/commit/61f9c4a4da95d0afc3634180eee3b65e38c54a14.

Finally, you could try out the next code implementation in Python, which is an adaptation of the function in the above link:

```
def to_positive_definitive(M):
    M = np.matrix(M)
    M = (M + M.T) * 0.5
    k = 1
    I = np.eye(M.shape[0])
    w, v = np.linalg.eig(M)
    min_eig = v.min()
    M += (-min_eig * k * k + np.spacing(min_eig)) * I
    return M

def validate_positive_definitive(M):   
    try:
        np.linalg.cholesky(M)
    except np.linalg.LinAlgError:
        M = to_positive_definitive(M)
    #Print the eigenvalues of the Matrix
    print(np.linalg.eigvalsh(p))
    return M
M = validate_positive_definitive(M)
print(M)
```

Comment: I have met same problem, can you explain more how to deal with it?